# Connect to secondary Database if primary is down

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

I'm looking for solution to switch to secondary DB if primary is unavailable. 
I have 2 connection strings and DBcontexts prepared. Both are SQL Servers, one on Azure and 2nd on AWS.

I thought of some kind of middleware maybe

Comment: So, are these two databases used separately or is one of them a back-up of the other?

Comment: Anyhow, the idea with having these things in a cloud platform is to utilize their built-in features to go for high availability. If you choose Basic, Standard or Premium tiers in Azure, you get a 99,9% [msft-sla](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/sql-database/v1_1/) so in my opinion, you shouldn't make any code handle this, but rely on the backend services to handle any faults/downtime. If you're using VMs, you can set up availability sets that allows for very low downtime on failures.

Comment: Do you want a cluster or a mirror?  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/windows-server-failover-clustering-wsfc-with-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @jwweiler second one is a replica.
The problem I introduced is for academic purposes, to evaluate the work of the solution we're talking about.

Comment: I'm aware of idea of cloud platforms, nevertheless I am tasked to offer a programming solution for that

Comment: All queries should be wrapped with "retry feature" if query fails with timeout for some reason - you will be able to retry it with another connection